# How to have text always visible while having different background animation on hover?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate background-color on element hover, but I can't make it so that the text remains always visible/on top. It seems that setting z-index doesn't do anything. Is there something else I should try to do?

```css
ul li {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

ul li:hover .bg:before {
  width: 50%;
}

.text {
  z-index: 999999999;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg:before {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2%;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="text">Hover over this text</div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` will not affect the text element because it is statically positioned as opposed to the bg element which is absolutely positioned. To remedy this you can add `position: relative;` to the text element:

```css
ul li {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

ul li:hover .bg:before {
  width: 50%;
}

.text {
  z-index: 999999999;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.bg:before {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2%;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="text">Hover over this text</div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) only works on positioned elements such as :

- position: absolute
- position: relative
- position: fixed

So add `position: relative;` to `.text` class

```css
ul li {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

ul li:hover .bg:before {
  width: 50%;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg:before {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2%;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="text">Hover over this text</div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```